# MRTK Add ManipulationHandler in C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk

I'm attempting to dynamically add Manipulation Events to a `ManipulationHandler` that is being added to child objects of a parent. The parent object will be what the user is inspecting, but the user will be able to grab parts off of the parent and inspect them more closely. (i.e. you can look at an engine (parent object), but if you want to inspect the pistons (child objects) you can grab them and look at them)

Instead of having to go into every child object and manually add it in Unity I'd like to be able to add the parent object and just procedurally add the `ManipulationHandler` and `ManipulationEvent`s on start or awake.

So far I have the following code for adding the `ManipulationHandler` script, but to add the `ManipulationEvent` I'm not sure how to set up the pointers so I can use the script and function I want from the source:

```
gameObject.AddComponent<ManipulationHandler>();
ManipulationHandler handler = gameObject.GetComponent<ManipulationHandler>();
ManipulationEvent newevent = new ManipulationEvent();
ManipulationEventData eventdata = new ManipulationEventData();
eventdata.ManipulationSource = gameObject;
```

The program works when I grab the objects, but I'd like to add manipulation events when I grab them so I can display additional data.

I see there's a getter and setter for Pointer in `ManipulationEventData`, but I'm not sure how to instantiate `IMixedRealityPointer` and how to get it to work. I'm also not sure if that's the object I actually need to accomplish what I'd like to accomplish.

I apologize in advance if I've missed something obvious. I'm new to MRTK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ManipulationHandler`](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_ManipulationHandler.html) has four [callback events](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_ManipulationHandler.html#events) among them `OnManipulationStarted` and `OnManipulationEnded` you can simply add listeners to. (see [`UnityEvent.AddListener`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.AddListener.html))

Unless I understood your question wrong you don't have to instantiate any `IMixedRealityPointer`. **You** don't create the event data yourself but rather the `ManipulationHandler` feeds these events with the current event data including the interacting pointer information. The `ManipulationHandler` uses `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerDragged` and `OnPointerUp` via the `IMixedRealityPointerHandler` interface in order to manage the interacting pointers and invokes the according events where needed.

Instead of using `AddComponent` followed by `GetComponent` directly store and use the return value of [`AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) which will be the reference of the newly added Component. MRTK also has an extension method

```c#
T EnsureComponent<T>(this Component component) where T : Component
```

so that you can simply use e.g.

```c#
var handler = this.EnsureComponent<ManipulationHandler>();
```

which internally first checks whether the component already exists, and if not it adds it.

Note that in order to enable near interactions you will also need a `NearInteractionGrabbable` so you should add this one too.

You also will have to make sure that your objects have some sort of `Collider` attached to the same `GameObject` as the `NearInteractionGrabbable`.

```c#
    ...
    gameObject.transform.EnsureComponnet<NearInteractionGrabbable>();
    var handler = gameObject.transform.EnsureComponnet<ManipulationHandler>();

    handler.OnManipulationStarted.AddListener(HandleOnManipulationStarted);
    handler.OnManipulationEnded.AddListener(HandleOnManipulationEnded);
    ...

/// <summary>
/// If you need it later you need to store the pointer since unfortunately in 
/// OnManipulationEnded the <see cref="ManipulationEventData.Pointer"/> is null
/// (no idea why they do it this way :D )
/// </summary>
private IMixedRealityPointer _pointer;    

private void HandleOnManipulationStarted(ManipulationEventData eventData)
{
    _pointer = eventData.Pointer;

    // whatever shall happen when manipulation started
}

private void HandleOnManipulationEnded(ManipulationEventData eventData)
{
    // whatever shall happen when manipulation ended
}
```

---

***Note***: I am not sure if this thing you are trying to achieve is possible with this architecture ... it is very possible that nesting various `ManipulationHanlder` leads to strange behavior here and there. Especially very small parts will be almost impossible to grab ...

Comment: Good call on the EnsureComponent. I'll make those changes accordingly.

Comment: As for the question I believe you hit it right on the nose with the UnityEvent and adding a listener. I found information regarding that last night after I posted this, but I'm still relatively new with reading API's and wasn't sure how to use it. Also, I'm not as well versed in adding listeners as I'd like. I believe you gave me what I need in order to do that.

Also, I've got the NearInteractionGrabbable stuff, so not to worry about that :)

Thanks!